# Get first char in str in list in list in one sentence in Python

Tags: python

For example `a = [['Avc'],['acac','ccaaa'],['Vaa','Qaavv']]`

Using a, Make `b = ['A','ac','VQ']` by One sentence

I tried by `b = [''+j[0] for i in a for j in i]`

but result is `['A','a','c','V','Q']`

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. You should give an example of the desired output for your examples a and b.

Comment: @MachineLearner His expectation is `b =['A','ac','VQ']`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Ah, now I get it :D.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
b = ["".join(s[0] for s in e) for e in a]
```

This produces:

```
['A', 'ac', 'VQ']
```

for `b`.

Comment: Thank you! It works! And I fixed my Question fomat.